# Swapping hard disks of systems with different configurations

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, operating-systems

I swapped hard disks of two systems, Windows 7 installed on both. Here are the configurations:
(1) Intel 845 chipset, Celeron processor 1.60 Ghz, 1 GB RAM, 80 GB hard disk
(2) Intel 945G chipset, Core 2 Duo processor 2.80 Ghz, 2 GB RAM, 160 GB hard disk

After swapping both systems are working fine same as before.

But before swapping my colleagues and my computer vendor were saying it will not work. They said the configuration difference is high, they have tried it on other systems with Windows XP installed and it don't work.

So I want to know is this just my luck or Windows 7 has such features? Is this possible with other operating systems also?

Answer (score 0):

They are probably working because of the OS and luck.  You can check by pulling up the PC's properties (right click Computer and then properties) and seeing if what windows detects is the same as the system you are running.  Another thing to test, is pull up task manager of the dual core system and see if it recognizes both cores.

However since the drivers are not the same for the two PC's, performance will be lower than if the correct drivers are installed.  I **highly** recommend you find and make sure to install all drivers for the system the hard drive is now currently on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Windows has detected all the hardware correctly. Both cores are working properly.

Comment: Cool man, then make sure the drivers are updated, and hopefully you don't have any probs.

Comment: KronoS is right - this kind of swap is very hit and miss and you got lucky!